# poll / epoll server - how to handle per connection data

Tags: c++, polling, epoll

I am writing linux network server using `poll` / `epoll`.

I plan to have lots of connected clients, say 5000 - 10000 or even 20000.

Each client will send some data as request, then server will send some data back. For the moment for simplicity I decided to limit this data to 16 KB.

I am using C++11.

As I see it,

- I can create huge "static" array of 16 KB blocks with total size of max clients e.g. for 10K connections - 10000 x 16 KB = 160 MB
- I can create array of buffers (`std::vector<char>`) and push_back there.
- I can create `std::vector` of buffers.

In all cases server will take 160 MB on full load, but if I use "static" array, there will be no any memory allocations / movements after initial allocation.

What is the best way to proceed and is there some other solution I am missing here.

Comment: `Never` create static buffers, even if you know beforehand their size; you'll never know if that size may change in the future, while your program is already running in an unstoppable, critical server. Not to mention that it fails to cooperate with the OS in order to distribute memory along all processs, and instead makes your program greedy.

Comment: @KemyLand nteresting point. I used word "static", but I am going to allocate this with `new` or `malloc`. Is this what you mean? Also both `max_clients` and `body_size` will be configurable.

Comment: I'ld be worse. With `static`, at least the OS can apply [COW semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) and lighten everything up a little. With `new`, most likely it can't.

Comment: The point is not the limits' configuration, but rather the fact that it may change *at runtime*.

Comment: @KemyLand I am completely lost :) Are you suggesting vector of vector-buffers and allocate / move / reallocate all the time?

Comment: No, of course no! You can use a `std::vector<whatever> vec`, and then `vec.reserve(10000)` in order to not needing to allocate for the next 10000 connections. However, if it gets over 10000 connections, you can either reserve again, or let the vector grow naturally. Either way, there'll be a considerable overhead if you surpass 10000 connections, but your program won't crash.

Comment: vec.reserve(10000) - this doing exactly the same as if I do malloc(10000 * sizeof vec::value_type) . In normal case, if there is more than 10000 connections, server will `accept()` them then will drop them immediately. Isn't it same as apache webserver? if you set MaxClients to 1000, there is no way for 1001 client to connect. It will fill backlog, then port will stop responding.

Comment: Well, in that case you should decided if you want to waste/use less memory or if you want to accept more clients.